# Creating a simple to view copy of a website

Tags: wordpress, html, clone, archive

One of my clients recently died, and her husband asked me if it's possible to take the website of his wives company offline, and make a copy for him, so he can keep it as a memory.

The website itself is a custom theme on Wordpress, so I created a local copy of the website with wget. This works fine but is not friendly for him to use. (The 80+ files that are required to show the page)

So I'm looking for a way to covert a 5 page website preferably into a single file, he can open and view from his iPad.

I thought about to just keep hosting a static copy out of curtesy, while I don't mind doing this I prefer a way where him being able to visit that memory is not depending on me still being in the hosting business in 5+ years.

Comment: Sorry for the loss... Try https://web.archive.org/? Or https://archive.is/ These both allow you to scrape legally and download the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if its not a very complex website, i.e. not involving a lot of extra scripts and stylesheets. In this case, you could save the displayed sourcecode of the 5 single pages as HTML files (from the browser) and also save the linked images, stylesheets and linked scripts. You would have to edit the menu links and maybe some other stuff (hard to say how much work without knowing the site), but that would at least be a possibility.